# Извлекаем определенные значения из массива и выводим их в новый массив

Tags: php, массивы

Имею вот такой массив:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 1234567892
>   [friend_status] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 123456744
>   [friend_status] => 0 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] =>
>   1236544885 [friend_status] => 0 ) )

Подскажите пожалуйста как добиться из него вот такого:

> Array ( [0] => 1234567892 [1] => 48359869 [2] => 123456744 [3] =>
>   1236544885 )

В коде имею вот так:

```
print_r($filteredArray);
```

То есть мне нужно, что-бы все имеющиеся `user_id` из первого  примера стали просто выводиться списком как во втором примере.

Спасибо!

Comment: `var_dump(array_map(function($user) { return $user->user_id; }, $your_array));`

Comment: var_dump можно было не писать, судя по тексту вопроса, автор это умеет :)

Comment: Что мне делать то с этим? Ничего не понимаю. а как отобразить?

Comment: @PHPcoder вам бы документацию почитать. Там все очень подробно хорошо описано и примеры есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо знать, как обращаться к свойствам объекта. Это принято делать через методы getdata() / setdata(), но в данном утилитарном случае мы обошлись без формальностей.
А потом мы в "прогулке" по массиву заменили объекты на id.

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = new stdClass();
$arr[0] -> user_id = 1234567892;
$arr[0] -> friend_status = 0;

$arr[1] = new stdClass();
$arr[1] -> user_id = 48359869;
$arr[1] -> friend_status = 0;

$arr[2] = new stdClass();
$arr[2] -> user_id = 123456744;
$arr[2] -> friend_status = 0;

$arr[3] = new stdClass();
$arr[3] -> user_id = 1236544885;
$arr[3] -> friend_status = 0;

var_dump($arr);
array_walk($arr, function(&$item){
    $item = $item->user_id;
});
var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'user_id' => int 1234567892
      public 'friend_status' => int 0
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'user_id' => int 48359869
      public 'friend_status' => int 0
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'user_id' => int 123456744
      public 'friend_status' => int 0
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'user_id' => int 1236544885
      public 'friend_status' => int 0
array (size=4)
  0 => int 1234567892
  1 => int 48359869
  2 => int 123456744
  3 => int 1236544885
```

Comment: Круто сделал)) Спасбо)

Comment: Поразмышлял напрягся и сделал.. теперь знаю умею :)

Comment: @PHPcoder Ноухау прежде всего! И надо поставить галочку на самом подходящем ответе (это сейчас я один), а то модераторам придётся напоминать.